# Lost my Laos departure card, what to do?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, laos

Before arrival in Laos, you need to fill out one of those two-part entry forms with one half for Arrival and one half for Departure.  The Arrival section is collected at Immigration and you're supposed to hand over the Departure section when leaving.

Due to a complicated but irrelevant story, one person in my group does not have their Departure card. We're flying out tomorrow. What, if anything, to do?

Comment: No idea how the cards work in Laos, but in HK which has the same system, you have plenty of blank departure cards available at exit passport control. The carbonated folio system just saves you time (not having to fill the same information twice), but as far as I understand it, there is no link between the two (other than the info you provide). Maybe it works the same in Laos?

Comment: Lao Airlines [say](https://laoairlines.com/en/arrival-document/): “For departure from Laos international airports,  Arrival – Departure Declaration forms  are available at the airport before proceeding to immigration counters.” That would suggest to me a system similar to that of HK, though it’s only a guess (hence the comment, not answer).

Comment: You probably will have to self answer this one with your direct experience, but it is highly likely that @jcaron is correct. The system in Laos is basically the same as Thailand or Hong Kong (although Thailand phased out the paper slips this year). I once lost the paper slip in Thailand and I just had to redo it at the airport when I departed. With any luck, it will be the same in Laos.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short and sweet: as @jcaron and @travelgasm correctly surmised, you can **just fill out another one**. At Vientiane airport, there were plenty of blank forms at the desks before passport control and nobody cares if the serial number on your Departure form matches the one on Arrival.